# Laravel is not parsing a JSON Object in Blade as expected - Error Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

I have a JSON Object like so:

```
{
  "statusCode": 0,
  "statusMessage": "OK",
  "content": {
    "templateId": "5a00775807105e735085c65d",
    "authorId": "fabio.peddis@bsc.it",
    "title": "Primo Template",
    "description": "Descrizione del Primo Template",
    "status": 0,
    "saveDate": 1509979998738,
    "publishDate": null,
    "keywords": [
      "keyDue",
      "keySecondo"
    ],
    "icon": null,
    "questions": [
      {
        "questionId": 1,
        "questionText": "Domanda 01?",
        "responses": [
          {
            "keywords": [
              "Sì",
              "Yes",
              "Oui"
            ],
            "nextQuestionId": 11
          },
          {
            "keywords": [
              "No",
              "Not",
              "Non"
            ],
            "nextQuestionId": 12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionId": 11,
        "questionText": "Domanda 11?",
        "responses": [
          {
            "keywords": [
```

I pass it to a view after doing this:

```
$objResp=json_decode($response);
```

Then on the view I simply access it like so:

```
@foreach($template->content->questions as $question)
    ... 
    {{$question->questionText}}   
    ...
    @foreach($question->responses as $res )
        ....
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

"Responses" is a different structure but at the same level as "questionText" that I can easily access it.

So the problem is in the second/internal loop, it crashes without hope..., but if I do a `dd()` of `$question->responses`, I can see the correct contents of an array size2.

Laravel gives me back this error with the loop:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$responses

What is causing this error?

Comment: Did you try to see what $question contains on each run? Also, posting the entire JSON somewhere so we can see it would help.

Comment: @Ynhockey the json is so long but contains the same structure without errors, trust me; $question contains what I expetct! if im doing a dd() or a var_Dump() the content showed to me is correct! like this: {#239 ▼
  +"questionId": 1
  +"questionText": "Domanda 01?"
  +"responses": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#240 ▼
      +"keywords": array:3 [▶]
      +"nextQuestionId": 11
    }
    1 => {#243 ▼
      +"keywords": array:3 [▶]
      +"nextQuestionId": 12
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a key for each response.

Like:

```
"responses": [
      "1": {
        "keywords": [
          "Sì",
          "Yes",
          "Oui"
        ],
        "nextQuestionId": 11
      },
      "2": {
        "keywords": [
          "No",
          "Not",
          "Non"
        ],
        "nextQuestionId": 12
      }
    ]
```

There is multiple ways to reresent json and I think this json syntax is not supported by php.

Comment: I need to consume it... i'm not who made it :( so i've no control over it for now!

Comment: This is the json format supported by php:
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc7159.html

So it would be good if you could specify to your source a json format. Could you?

Answer (score 0):

Pass true as the second argument to `json_decode`.

`$objResp=json_decode($response, true);`